# UI Testing Failure - Failure getting snapshot for element Error -25201

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing, cocoapods-1.0.1

I currently encountered this issue while running my UI Tests for iOS

> Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - Failure getting snapshot Error Domain=XCTestManagerErrorDomain Code=9 "Error -25201 getting snapshot for element  {pid=84523}" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error -25201 getting snapshot for element  {pid=84523}}

Currently using Xcode 7.3.1, Cocoapods 1.0.1.

I tried deleting DerivedData, Pods/, Podfile.lock and *.xcworkspace and running pod install afterwards. No luck. Still experiencing the error. First experienced in Xcode 7.3. Upgraded it and issue still persists.

Anybody who experienced the same thing and resolved the problem? Kindly share your solution. Thank you.

Comment: Have the same issue. It looks like this radar http://www.openradar.me/25623858

Comment: The thing is, it only happens on my macbook. I let my friend try to run the code on his macbook and it ran fine. So I was forced to reformat the machine. Still, the issue persists.

Comment: I let my colleague run the same code again, now he's encountering the same issue. Looks like it's not an isolated case anymore. Anyone here who encountered the same and resolved the problem?

Comment: This problem is still happening in Xcode 8.1 UI Testing Failure - Failure getting snapshot Error Domain=XCTestManagerErrorDomain Code=9

Comment: Guys, if you use Appium, update it to the latest beta and your issue will be solved

Comment: Are you trying to access a cell in a tableview?

Answer (score 2):

The link https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/129839#129839 claims that this has multiple causes, all being bugs that haven't been fixed yet.  There are some possible solutions in that post.  You need an Apple Developer account to see it.